# Names for matrix diagonals other than the main diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For example, for an [n x n] matrix does the kth diagonal where k = n/2 have a name? Maybe the "half-diagonal"?

Comment: For $k=n/2$ (you can choose ceiling/floor at your own leisure), the term "half-diagonal" sounds reasonable!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A standard terminology is that the $k$'th superdiagonal is $k$ entries above/right of the main diagonal, and the $k$'th subdiagonal is $k$ entries below/left of the main diagonal.  The first superdiagonal may be called "the superdiagonal", and the first subdiagonal may be called "the subdiagonal".  I don't know of any other names...